# f:setPropertyActionListener randomly not invoked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm facing a strange behaviour of `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` tag. Sometimes and more strangely, randomly it stops working thus not calling setter method before action begins (I've quickly translated messages from Italian just to show you what's going).
Here it is:

```
<p:treeTable value="#{addestramentoController.addestramenti}"
             id="addestramentiTree"
             var="addr" scrollable="true"
             scrollHeight="200"
             emptyMessage="No training in database.">

    <f:facet name="header">
        Training List
    </f:facet>

    <p:column .... />

    <p:column style="width:20px; text-align: center">
        <p:commandLink rendered="#{(addr.dataAddestramento ne null)}"
                       oncomplete="PF('confirmDlg').show()"
                       title="Delete training"
                       styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">

            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{addr}"
                                        target="{addestramentoController.item}"/>
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

Here is the dialog, in the same page and inside the same form:

```
<!-- Confirm Dialog -->
<p:confirmDialog id="confirm"
                 widgetVar="confirmDlg"
                 message="Delete training?"
                 header="Confirm"
                 severity="alert"
                 closeOnEscape="true">

    <p:commandButton value="Yes"
                     action="#{addestramentoController.doDelete}"
                     update="addestramentiTree nuovoAddestramento"
                     oncomplete="PF('confirmDlg').hide();"
                     icon="ui-icon-check"/>

    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                     onclick="PF('confirmDlg').hide();"
                     icon="ui-icon-close"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
<!-- ////////////// -->
```

The `AddestramentoController` backing bean is done using Java EE 7 CDI annotation. Here is the relevant part:

```
public void setItem(VolAddestramento item) {
    // Really this should NEVER happen!
    if (item == null) {
        setDialogMessage(new DialogMessage("Error", "Error Message"));
    }
    this.item = item;
}

public void doDelete() {
    // Delete selected training
    aServ.deleteAddestramento(item);

    // Update table data
    fillAddestramenti();
}
```

`aServ` in an EJB and everything works fine, but sometimes not. `setItem` is not called at all causing a NPE in EJB service method. As you can see in `<p:dialog>` I used `action` but I've also tried with `actionListener`. I don't know what's wrong in my code, but it's the same used in PrimeFaces showcase and should work out of the box. I've never faced the problem during my development tests and it only (apparently) happens on deployment environment.

These are my development and deployment setups :

**Development**: JDK 8u25_x64 - NB 8.0.2 - GF 4.1 with PrimeFaces 5.1 Community using Mojarra 2.2.7 impl.

**Deployment**: JDK 8u25_x64 - Wildfly 8.0.0Final with Mojarra 2.2.5-jbossorg-3

Maybe a problem of Mojarra?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**: Well, forget to tell...the backing bean is a `ViewScoped` one.

Comment: Does that `<p:confirmDialog>` appear, when you click the given `<p:commandLink>` (I assume it should according to `oncomplete="PF('confirmDlg').show()"`)? The `process` attribute of `<p:commandLink>` defaults to `@form`. Hence, the symptom might be that it might cause some unintentional behaviour sometimes by processing/executing the whole form unnecessarily, when it is clicked. Could you please try setting the `process` attribute of that `<p:commandLink>` to `@this` such as `<p:commandLink process="@this"...>`?

Comment: Also, you forgot a `#` here - `target="{addestramentoController.item}"`. It should look like `target="#{addestramentoController.item}"` instead. Look closely (unless it is a typo).

Comment: @Tiny the # was a typo due to copy-paste. Yes the dialog appears and the action starts but the listener is not called (randomly or only after first time? don't know). I will try putting `process="@this"` properties and let you know. Thank you.